# Программа для конструирования SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите программу, на которой можно было бы быстро сконструировать архитектуру базы данных, а затем просто скопировать SQL код?

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
([скачать](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/))

- Бесплатная (условия см. на сайте)
- Проектирование и моделирование
- Разработка SQL
- Администрирование
- Миграции

Answer (score 0):

http://www.activequerybuilder.com/

https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-query-builder.html

И прочее [источник](http://www.askdev.ru/question/9768/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-SQL-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/)

см больше по запросу **визуальный конструктор sql запросов**

Answer (score 0):

[Caseberry](http://caseberry.net/) - CASE-инструмент, позволяющий моделировать в нотации UML

[ErWin](http://erwin.com/resources/software-trials) - среда моделирования данных